# Javascript loading speed issue as variable increases

Tags: javascript, performance, function, page-load-time, slowdown

I am having an issue with page loading time. Currently right now I am running UBUNTU in Oracle Vm Virtual Box. I am using mozilla firefox as my browser and I am working on an etchasketch project from "The odin project".

My problem is the page loading time. The code takes a prompt at the start and generates a grid for the etch a sketch based on that prompt. I have not given it the minimum and maximum values (16 and 64) respectively, however any number when prompted at the beginning that is beyond 35 doesn't load or takes ages to load.

How do I speed up the process time? / why is it moving so slow? / how can I avoid this ? / is there a fix that I am over looking that can make this work a lot faster? / feel free to tackle any and all of those questions!

This is my HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>
  </title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="etchhead">
  <p> Choose your grid size </p>
  <input type = "text"></input>
  <button id="startOver"> Clear Grid </button>
  <p> Change color </p>
</div>

<div id="grid">
</div>

<script src="eas.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
  p {
      color: blue;
      display: inline;
  }

    #grid {
      display: grid;
      width: 800px;
      max-width: 800px;
      height: 800px;
      max-height: 800px;
      line-height: 0;

    }

    .gridBox {
      border:  1px solid black;
      background-color: lightgrey
    }
```

And this is my JAVASCRIPT code:

```
 gridStart();

  function gridStart(){
  var boxes = 0
  var selectBody = document.querySelector("#grid");
  var addBox = document.createElement("div");
  var boxCountStart = prompt("enter a number between 16 and 64");
  var boxDimensions = (boxCountStart * boxCountStart);

  function rowsAndColumns() {
    var selectBody = document.querySelector("#grid");
    var gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat('+boxCountStart+', 1fr)';
    selectBody.style.gridTemplateColumns= gridTemplateColumns;
    selectBody.style.gridTemplateRows= gridTemplateColumns;
};

 function hoverColor(){
   var divSelector = selectBody.querySelectorAll("div");
   divSelector.forEach((div) => {
     div.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
       event.target.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
 });
 });
 };

 rowsAndColumns();

for (boxes = 0; boxes < boxDimensions ; boxes++) {
  var selectBody = document.querySelector("#grid");
  var addBox = document.createElement("div");
        addBox.classList.add("gridBox");
        addBox.textContent = (" ");
        selectBody.appendChild(addBox);
        hoverColor();
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two components to your issue. One is that you are repeatedly modifying the DOM in a loop. You can fix it by appending all your boxes to a DocumentFragment and then adding that to the DOM after your loop finishes. You are also calling `hoverColor();` inside your loop which results in adding tons of event listeners that all do the same thing (since inside hoverColor you are adding a listener to every single div). You can fix both those issues like this:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment( );

for (var i = 0; i < boxDimensions ; i++) {
  var addBox = document.createElement("div");
  addBox.classList.add("gridBox");
  addBox.textContent = (" ");
  fragment.appendChild(addBox);
}

document.querySelector("#grid").appendChild( fragment );
hoverColor();
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qhLvs94z/) with your original code, and [here is one](https://jsfiddle.net/qhLvs94z/1/) with the modification.

You could also benefit from only having one event listener total. You don't need to loop and add an event listener to every div. Just add one to `#grid` and use `event.target` (like you already do, to find the div that the event originated from). Something like this:

```
function hoverColor(){
    document.querySelector("#grid").addEventListener( 'mouseover', function ( event ) {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    } );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch paul. Worked like a charm! if I had more reputation points I'd upvote you haha!